# How to make copy of a file from default theme in magento 2 for modifications

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

I have file success.phtml in directory of Magento 2

```
C:\wamp\www\magento_test\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml
```

I want to make some changes in this, and also want to keep the source file as it is..

Made a new theme under directory and modify file success.phtml but didn't work

```
C:\wamp\www\magento_test\app\design\frontend\Yard\yardfreak\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates/success.phtml
```

Please suggest me , the right directory structure for file that loads first then the above give directory if file didn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working now ...

1. directory should be like this

   ```
   C:\wamp\www\magento_test\app\design\frontend\Yard\yardfreak\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml
   ```